# Is there an easy way to do encryption/decryption on columns in a Grails domain class?

Tags: grails, encryption, grails-2.0

I need to decrypt/encrypt a few columns in my domain class and am looking for information on how to do so.  I've found the jasypt encryption plugin, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be compatible with Grails 2.4

I could probably cobble something together, but want to make sure Im following best practices and would also prefer not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Looks like someone submitted a PR to fix the compatibility issue, but the BitBucket repo is "pending transfer to bloomhealth":
https://bitbucket.org/tednaleid/grails-jasypt/pull-requests

Comment: I haven't used/maintained that plugin since I left bloomhealth in 2011.  They were supposed to take it over, but apparently haven't.  For now, I'd consider it abandoned, but if someone wanted to take it over and maintain it, they're welcome to it.

Answer (score 0):

static mapping ={
        userId type: GormEncryptedStringType
        password type: GormEncryptedStringType
    }